# save pickle with dublicate objects - or - save python formulas formulas.excel.ExcelModel

Tags: python, excel, formula, pickle

I have a huge xls which I parsed using the formulas package in python. As loading and converting the xls takes some time I am searching for a way to save the formulas.excel.ExcelModel object. I tried pickle (and json and klepto) but with pickle I get the following error:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <function bypass at 0x0000021A8B6D8620>: it's not the same object as schedula.utils.dsp.bypass
```

as there are parts that have similar names. Is there a flag or something that I can set in pickle to ignore this error? Or is there another way to save this object?

Below is a code that reproduces the error:

```
import formulas
import xlsxwriter
import pickle

# generate a fake workbook
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('./test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
testdata = (['a', 1000],
            ['b',   100])

#add values to rows and columns and ...  
worksheet.write(0, 0, testdata[0][0])
worksheet.write(0, 1, testdata[0][1])
worksheet.write(1, 0, testdata[1][0])
worksheet.write(1, 1, testdata[1][1])

#... finally sum them up
worksheet.write(2, 0, 'Total')
worksheet.write(2, 1, '=SUM(B1:B2)')
workbook.close()

# now load and convert the xls using formulas
xl = formulas.ExcelModel().loads("./test.xlsx").finish()

# and here the error occurs if I try to pickle it
with open('./model.pkl','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(xl,f)
```